# The name “StatConverter” does not exist in the namespace

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

[image]

```
 <Window
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:xcdg="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/datagrid" xmlns:LiteTreeView="clr-namespace:LiteTreeView;assembly=LiteTreeView" x:Class="test.date_changes"
            Title="date_changes" Height="600" Width="1200"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test">

        <Window.Resources>

            <local:StatConverter x:Key="Converter"></local:StatConverter>
        </Window.Resources>
    </window>


    namespace test
    {
        public class StatConverter : IValueConverter
        {
            #region IValueConverter Members

            public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {
                if (value is int)
                {
                    return (int)value == 1;
                }

                return false;
            }

            public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            #endregion
        }
    }
```

Getting error `The name “StatConverter” does not exist in the namespace`. Searched similar question,Tried with different solution(like changing debug to release).But could not fix it.Please help me to solve this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please post an image of your Solution Explorer?

Comment: I guess the error is reported by XAML editor? well if so try compiling and running your project anyway. Don't believe in what XAML editor reports to you, in some cases it's just wrong (after building, it may be correct again).

Comment: Your closing tag... </window> does not appear to match the declaration.  Not sure if this has anything to do with it, but something that should be fixed regardless.

Comment: Is the StatConverter in the same assembly as the test.date_changes?

Comment: statConverter in same assembly

Comment: @RashmiS Did you try specifying assembly directive also adjacent to namespace declaration and rebuild/run application?

Comment: tried with  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test;Assembly="

Comment: The declaration format should be like: xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NAMESPACE;assembly=ASSEMBLYNAME"